# How do I stop my computer from crashing?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash

Recently, I've been having problems with my late 2009 MacBook Pro crashing several times a day. How can I fix it?

I'm running OS 10.7.3 with 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: 13-inch or 15-inch?

Comment: 15 inches diagonally.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29426/help-my-computer-doesnt-work

Comment: Which diagonal? If they're not both 15" your screen may be a parallelogram

Comment: @KyleCronin Hadn't thought about that! I just checked and the top-left-to-bottom-right diagonal is exactly 17" but the bottom-left-to-top-right diagonal is 16.996"! (Apparently I was wrong about the 15 inches.) I have been cheated of—(hang on, let me do the math)

Comment: @KyleCronin My math just proved I'm an idiot. I still have the same number of pixels, but my screen's a bit lopsided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a setting that Apple has for some reason decided to hide completely, and can easily be fixed with a few simple steps.

1. First, go to /System/Library/CoreServices/ and right-click on Finder. Select Show Package Contents, navigate to …/Contents/Info.plist and open it in TextEdit.
2. Near the bottom, below the last `</array>` but before the last `</dict>`, add the following two lines of code:
   `<key>ShowCrashPrefs</key>`
   `<true/>`
3. Save and quit TextEdit. Hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd> while clicking on the Finder icon and select Relaunch. Once Finder fully loads again, advance to step 4.
4. Open Finder preferences with Finder > Preferences… or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and navigate to the Advanced tab. Tick the "Show crash prefpane in System Preferences" option.
   [image: Finder Prefs]
5. Launch System preferences and select the new Crash icon, under **System**. When it loads, drag the crash frequency slider to Min.

[image: System Prefs]

Comment: Here’s a one-liner that you can use in Terminal.app instead of step 1 and 2: `defaults write NSGlobalDomain ShowCrashPrefs -bool true`. It should be noted that on pre-Lion OS X versions, the “Max” label says “Windows mode” instead.

Comment: @MathiasBynens Good catch!

Comment: What happens if Crash frequency is set for a negative value?